# auto-py-to-exe "'extra' does not exist in evaluation environment."

Tags: pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I'm trying to learn how to convert my Python projects into .exe's so they can be distributed to my coworkers without them needing to install and manage a Python environment. The problem is that every time I try I get the error  `File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\packaging\markers.py", line 215, in _get_env raise UndefinedEnvironmentName( packaging.markers.UndefinedEnvironmentName: 'extra' does not exist in evaluation environment.` I've checked the FAQs, I've tried using auto-py-to-exe installed from a pip environment and from a conda environnment, and I've double checked that all dependencies are installed in the virtual environment, what should my next steps in troubleshooting be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a newer version of the packaging module.

> pip install --upgrade packaging

Or:

> python -m pip install --upgrade packaging

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.